# Updating a Table by counting results from 2 another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to update the table T1 by counting the results of a SQL Query from other tables T2 and T3.

This is the query I came up with but it does not seem to work:

```
UPDATE T1
set Stock =
(SELECT count(ID_Item)
                 FROM T2,T3
                 WHERE T2.ID_Product = T1.ParentSKU AND
            T3.ID = T2.ID_Product AND
            Stock_Items.Name = '' AND
            Stock_Items.Returned = ''

        GROUP BY(T3.Size)
                )
```

What I am trying to do is to update T1 by counting the results from T2 and grouping distinct sizes from T3.

Comment: mysql or sql-server?

Comment: what doesn't seem to work? do you get any error?

Comment: it is a mysql server

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your non-working query does not provide enough information.

Comment: Remove `GROUP BY(T3.Size)` and put it as a `WHERE` clause, for the size you are updating. Other wise your subquery will return more than one value if there are different sizes, and that will cause it to fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `GROUP BY`, if your item has more than one size your subquery will return multiple results, and the update will fail.

```
UPDATE T1
set Stock =
(SELECT count(ID_Item)
                 FROM T2 INNER JOIN T3
                 WHERE T2.ID_Product = T1.ParentSKU AND
            T3.ID = T2.ID_Product AND
            Stock_Items.Name = '' AND
            Stock_Items.Returned = '' AND
            T3.Size = T1.Size
                )
```

if Size is not a factor, then remove it completely from the subquery

Comment: Thank you however this query updates the stock for only 1 size per T1.ParentSKU. I need it to update all sizes per T1.ParentSKU.

Comment: @PierreS. Have you actually tested it, or are you merely assuming? perhaps show us you real table structure. if you have multiple sizes, you have to count per `ParentSKU, Size` combination. I suspect you actual query is different from what you provided

Comment: You are correct, I made a mistake in my query. You solution was perfect. Thank you again.